# What kind of output does True or False give you?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I was working on proving that a statement ...

$ p \to \lnot(\lnot q  \land  (p \to q))$

... is a tautology using logical equivalences and wound up at this step:

$ T \lor F $

I'm unsure if the output would be true or not, or if its too ambiguous to get an answer from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\lor$ is true iff at least one of the disjuncts is true. So, $T \lor F = T$